# How to read data from .log file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a log file with data from 100 pages from a webscrape script.
the .log file are read in log like this:

```
Title: Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM
Price: 6�900 kr
Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=161065896
21-Oct-19 10:21:14 - Found:
Title: Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM
Price: 7�500 kr
Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=155541389
21-Oct-19 10:21:14 - Found:
Title: Panasonic Lumix G 25mm F1.4 ASPH
Price: 3�200 kr
Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=161066674
```

I would like to import this data and send it to excel like

```
title           price      link
canon 100mm     6900kr     https
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach need to be changed if the log file is not in the order you have shown. As the following function will always start to find the Title, Price and Link text and add to a list. To convert to dataframe the all list need to be equal length. Let me know if it works.

```
def log_to_frame(location="./datalake/file.log"):
    with open(location, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        title_list = []
        price_list = []
        link_list = []
        for line in f:
            if "Title" in line:
                title = line.split(": ")[1].rstrip()
                title_list.append(title)
            elif "Price" in line:
                price = line.split(": ")[1].replace("�", "").rstrip()
                price_list.append(title)
            elif "Link" in line:
                link = line.split(": ")[1].rstrip()
                link_list.append(title)
            else:
                pass
    main_df = pd.DataFrame({"title": title_list, "price": price_list, "link": link_list})
    return main_df


log_df = log_to_frame()
log_df.to_excel("log.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: I did not gettit to work so am not sure if its i that dont understand it, but i did something happen:  
  
```import pandas as pd

user_cols = ['Title', 'Price', 'Link']
users = pd.read_csv('finn.no-2019-10-21-.txt', sep ='Line')

print(users)
```

Comment: You can not read a log file like that, because that format is not known to pandas. So you must need to preprocess each file before read it in to dataframe. It will do something for sure but not in the correct way. So you need to separate each Title, Price and Link as a separate set any how and then create the dataframe and append the frame..

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data into a DataFrame as a normal table and then combine the columns using the DataFrame's `log` and `reset_index` functions.
This assumes that there is only one ":" symbol on each line, separating the "key" column from the "value" column, and that every "record" has a line for every key.

```
import pandas as pd

p = pd.read_table("table.log", sep=':', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame()
keys = set(p[0]) # set of all unique keys

for key in keys:
  # get all values with the current key and re-index them from 0...n
  col_data = p.loc[p[0]==key][1].reset_index(drop=True)
  # put this in a new column named after the key
  df[key] = col_data
```